# Filter PNGs whose filenames end in "_Normal" using preset manager

Tags: unity, textures, importing, asset-workflow

I have made specific presets for textures like Normal or Emission maps. After they are imported I have to manually select each one and assign the proper preset.

I want to automate this process. To do this, [Unity has preset filters](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PresetManager.html).

The problem is I can't get the syntax to work. I have tried so many variations of the documentation examples, but nothing works.

Example:

Let's say I want every png file which ends in "_Normal" to get a specific preset value.

[image: Preset manager screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the example was this: glob:"*_Normal.png"